# Spark DataFrame column from downloaded data from s3-filepath given in each row of another column

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a Spark DataFrame with a column where each row has an S3-path to a json file.

```
+----------------------------------------+
|s3path                                  |
+----------------------------------------+
|s3a://mybucket/prefix/to/myfile0001.json|
|s3a://mybucket/prefix/to/myfile0002.json|
|s3a://mybucket/prefix/to/myfile0003.json|
|...                                     |
|s3a://mybucket/prefix/to/myfile000x.json|
+----------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to create another column in the same DataFrame where each row would contain the json data of the json file given in the `s3path` column?  Preferably without using a UDF.

I can modify the approach given by James S Hocking in this Medium article to make calls to the aws api rather than rest, but would prefer not to have to use a UDF.
https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-execute-a-rest-api-call-on-apache-spark-the-right-way-in-python-4367f2740e78

Comment: Without UDF can not make HTTP request to fetch JSON from S3.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, which works, but I would still prefer a solution that does not require a UDF.

Where the `s3path` column is modified to only have the s3 path past the bucket name, e.g. `prefix/to/myfile0001.json`.

```py
import boto3
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

@F.udf(returnType=T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
def load_external(s3path):
    session_prod = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id=KEY_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY_ID,
            region_name=REGION)
    s3 = session_prod.client('s3')

    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket="mybucket", Key=s3path)
    res = json.loads(obj.get('Body').read())
    string_list = [d.get("Text") for d in res[0].get('Blocks')]

    return string_list

df = df.withColumn("string_list", load_external(F.col("s3path")))
```